# Wie gendert man Absenderadresse?

Tags: gender-neutrality

Kann man Absendeadresse sagen?

Wenn ich nach "Absendeadresse vs Absenderadresse" [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Absendeadresse%20vs%20Absenderadresse), bekomme ich Ergebnisse für "Absenderadresse vs Absenderadresse" vorgeschlagen, woraus ich schließe, dass Google meint, "Absendeadresse" sei kein richtiges deutsches Wort. Deswegen die Frage.

Answer (score 3):

Du kannst im Deutschen Wörter zusammensetzen, wie es dir gefällt, die Frage ist eigentlich nur, ob das Ergebnis für andere verständlich ist. Das ist bei "Absendeadresse" sicherlich der Fall. Etablierte gegenderte Formen existieren für sehr viele Wörter (noch?) nicht, und es gibt auch keine Instanz, die diese festlegen kann. Wenn man das Gendern grundsätzlich für sinnvoll hält, darf und muss man halt kreativ werden.

Absendeadresse, Absender[*_:/][Ii]nnenAdresse, Absendendenadresse ... -- alles möglich (zumindest wenn man nicht für eine Entität schreibt, die den Regeln des Rechtschreibrates unterliegt, der die Formen mit Stern, Doppelpunkt oder Unterstrich nicht zulässt). Da die Mehrheit der Sprachgemeinschaft bekanntlich das Gendern ablehnt, zum Teil sehr vehement, stellt sich auch die Frage, wie man sich selbst in dieser Frage seinen Lesern darstellen möchte, und je nachdem werden unterschiedliche Autoren jeweils unauffälligere oder auffälligere Formen bevorzugen, oder das generische Maskulinum. Das gehört zur persönlichen Freiheit, sich auszudrücken.

Answer (score 1):

Ein richtiges (wenn auch nicht notwendigerweise gängiges) deutsches Wort ist "Absendeadresse" durchaus.

Neben der hohen Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass man es als unbeabsichtigtes Resultat aus einem Tippfehler einstuft, da es sehr nahe an einem tatsächlich gängigen Wort ("Absenderadresse") liegt, sehe ich das Hauptproblem darin, dass die zwei Begriffe inhaltlich nicht synonym zu sein scheinen:

Die "Absenderadresse", ganz gleich, wie man zur Inklusivität des Wortes "Absender" stehen mag, bezieht sich auf den Absender, also die Entität, von welcher die Sendung stammt. Unter einer "Absenderadresse" erwarte ich den Namen einer Person oder Organisation, sowie Straße, Stadt und ggf. Land.

Eine "Absendeadresse" klingt hingegen vielmehr danach, als gehe es um die Handlung des Absendens. Wer die Sendung veranlasst, bleibt dabei außen vor. Würde mich jemand explizit nach einer "Absendeadresse" fragen, würde ich intuitiv nur Straße, Stadt und ggf. Land angeben.

Comment: oder die Adresse der Poststation bei der abgesendet wurde?

Comment: @ceving: Auch eine Möglichkeit - worauf ich hinauswollte, ist, dass "Absenderadresse" für mich eher "Wer hat versandt und wo ist er?" impliziert, während "Absendeadresse" mich eher an "Wo wurde versandt?" denken lässt.